# What happens when I copy or move a file between different directories of a SMB file server?

Tags: windows, networking, smb, file-server

I'm wondering if moving or copying files between directories that belong to the same SMB server involves  the files moving over the network from the original directory to my pc, and then again from my pc to the  destination directory.

For example, what will happen when I copy the file "foo.bar" from the directory \\192.168.1.1\foo to the directory \\192.168.1.1\bar ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move files between two Windows file shares on the same server](http://superuser.com/q/503013/354511), [Copy remote files on NFS without round-trip](http://superuser.com/q/337778/354511), [How can I copy a file from one location to another location on the same server without the “echo”](http://superuser.com/q/332132/354511), and [Moving files on the same hard drive on a remote server](http://superuser.com/q/505144/354511). Related: [XCOPY behavior copying between remote servers](http://superuser.com/q/331180/354511).

Comment: Are you asking for the details on HOW this process works, or do you have a specific issue that you hope the answer to this question will solve for you?

Comment: If it's to different directories on the same same under \foo it'll do an internal move, but if it's from one share to another, that's a copy/delete operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy will transfer from one directory to the other through *your* machine.  This seems counter intuitive since the source and destination are on the same machine, but the remote machine is not aware of this.

Comment: "through your machine" means there are 2 transfers involved, copy foo.bar from \\192.168.1.1\foo to my machine & copy foo.bar from my machine to \\192.168.1.1\bar. It seems like the roundabout way, but doesn't the SMB server identify the source and destination IP match and try to transfer using a LAN Free (without Network) Path. Is this a limitation of SMB or is it technically not possible ?